# Why does the onclick event listener gets removed?

Tags: javascript

I am making a small matching game in javascript. Why does the onclick listener stop working after the first successful attempt. How do I rectify this issue.

I am expecting the listener to be attached to the last child element of the div with id "leftSide" even after I refresh all nodes by removing old nodes first.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Matching Game</title>
        <style>
            img {
                position: absolute;
            }

            div {
                position: absolute;
                width: 500px;
                height: 500px;
            }

            #rightSide {
                left: 500px;
                border-left: 1px solid black;
            }                    
        </style>        
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2>Matching Game</h2>
        <p>Click on the extra smile on the left</p>
        <div id="leftSide"></div>
        <div id="rightSide"></div>
        <script>
            var numberOfFaces = 5;
            var theLeftSide = document.getElementById("leftSide");
            var theRightSide = document.getElementById("rightSide");

            function generateFaces() {
                for (var i=0; i<=numberOfFaces; i++) {
                    new_img = document.createElement("img");
                    new_img.src="smile.png";
                    new_img.style.top=String(Math.floor(Math.random()*400))+"px";
                    new_img.style.left=String(Math.floor(Math.random()*400))+"px";
                    theLeftSide.appendChild(new_img);                    
                }

                // Clone all images to right side
                leftSideImages = theLeftSide.cloneNode(true);
                leftSideImages.removeChild(leftSideImages.lastChild);
                theRightSide.appendChild(leftSideImages);
            }

            generateFaces()

            var theBody = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];

            theBody.onclick = function gameOver() {
                alert("Game Over!");

                theBody.onclick = null;
                theLeftSide.lastChild.onclick = null;
            };

            theLeftSide.lastChild.onclick = function nextLevel(event) {
                // remove child nodes
                while (theLeftSide.firstChild) {
                    theLeftSide.removeChild(theLeftSide.firstChild);
                }

                while (theRightSide.firstChild) {
                    theRightSide.removeChild(theRightSide.firstChild);
                }

                // new nodes
                event.stopPropagation();
                numberOfFaces += 5;
                generateFaces();
            };


        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `generateFaces()` without semicolon, right after function declaration. Does it persist in your code?

Comment: Just tried, same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is when you attach an event handler to an element, when that element is destroyed, the event is gone too (when the GC cleans). The `theLeftSide.lastChild` doesn't creates a reference to whatever last child element of `theLeftSide` is. It creates a reference to the **current** last child.

You must change the place you add the event handler to inside your `generateFaces` function, so everytime you change the `theLeftSide` children, you get again the last child, and add the event.

Take a look at the example below:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Matching Game</title>
  <style>
    img {
      position: absolute;
    }
    div {
      position: absolute;
      width: 500px;
      height: 500px;
    }
    #rightSide {
      left: 500px;
      border-left: 1px solid black;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <h2>Matching Game</h2>
  <p>Click on the extra smile on the left</p>
  <div id="leftSide"></div>
  <div id="rightSide"></div>
  <script>
    var numberOfFaces = 5;
    var theLeftSide = document.getElementById("leftSide");
    var theRightSide = document.getElementById("rightSide");

    function generateFaces() {
      for (var i = 0; i <= numberOfFaces; i++) {
        new_img = document.createElement("img");
        new_img.src = "http://www.webgranth.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/smile.png";
        new_img.style.top = String(Math.floor(Math.random() * 400)) + "px";
        new_img.style.left = String(Math.floor(Math.random() * 400)) + "px";
        theLeftSide.appendChild(new_img);
      }

      // Clone all images to right side
      leftSideImages = theLeftSide.cloneNode(true);
      leftSideImages.removeChild(leftSideImages.lastChild);
      theRightSide.appendChild(leftSideImages);
      
      theLeftSide.lastChild.onclick = nextLevel;
    }

    generateFaces()

    var theBody = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];

    theBody.onclick = function gameOver() {
      alert("Game Over!");

      theBody.onclick = null;
      theLeftSide.lastChild.onclick = null;
    };

    function nextLevel(event) {
      // remove child nodes
      while (theLeftSide.firstChild) {
        theLeftSide.removeChild(theLeftSide.firstChild);
      }

      while (theRightSide.firstChild) {
        theRightSide.removeChild(theRightSide.firstChild);
      }

      // new nodes
      event.stopPropagation();
      numberOfFaces += 5;
      generateFaces();
    };
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

---

Note: I've simpled changed the `theLeftSide.lastChild.onclick = function nextLevel(event) {`, to a simple function declaration: `function nextLevel(event) {`, and then added the event handler inside the `generateFaces` function: `theLeftSide.lastChild.onclick = nextLevel;`.

Answer (score 1):

you could try something like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Matching Game</title>
        <style>
            img {
                position: absolute;
            }

            div {
                position: absolute;
                width: 500px;
                height: 500px;
            }

            #rightSide {
                left: 500px;
                border-left: 1px solid black;
            }                    
        </style>        
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2>Matching Game</h2>
        <p>Click on the extra smile on the left</p>
        <div id="leftSide"></div>
        <div id="rightSide"></div>
        <script>
            var numberOfFaces = 5;
            var theLeftSide = document.getElementById("leftSide");
            var theRightSide = document.getElementById("rightSide");

            var clickLastChild = function clickLastChild() {
                // remove child nodes

                theLeftSide.lastChild.onclick = function (event) {
                    while (theLeftSide.firstChild) {
                        theLeftSide.removeChild(theLeftSide.firstChild);
                    }

                    while (theRightSide.firstChild) {
                        theRightSide.removeChild(theRightSide.firstChild);
                    }

                    // new nodes
                    event.stopPropagation();
                    numberOfFaces += 5;
                    generateFaces();
                };
            };

            function generateFaces() {
                for (var i = 0; i <= numberOfFaces; i++) {
                    new_img = document.createElement("img");
                    new_img.src = "smile.png";
                    new_img.style.top = String(Math.floor(Math.random() * 400)) + "px";
                    new_img.style.left = String(Math.floor(Math.random() * 400)) + "px";
                    theLeftSide.appendChild(new_img);
                }

                // Clone all images to right side
                leftSideImages = theLeftSide.cloneNode(true);
                leftSideImages.removeChild(leftSideImages.lastChild);
                theRightSide.appendChild(leftSideImages);
                clickLastChild();
            }

            generateFaces();

            var theBody = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];

            theBody.onclick = function gameOver() {
                alert("Game Over!");

                theBody.onclick = null;
                theLeftSide.lastChild.onclick = null;
            };
            
            clickLastChild();

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here i made fully working [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/errhunter/rqpuw7xs/)

You have to call `generateFaces()` from game over scenario also. 
And yes as @epascarello mentioned, you are losing click events as you are setting them to null.

Comment: Your code had the same issues as the one mentioned above by Sourabh ... Your lastchild.click should be within the generateFaces()

Answer (score -1):

Because you set the onclick to false

```
theBody.onclick = null;
theLeftSide.lastChild.onclick = null;
```

when you click the tbody.